# create charts based on condition in Qlik Sense

Tags: qliksense

I have my data where the important columns are - date_a, date_b, date_c

in a bar chart I need to show the X axis - pass and fail, and Y axis - counts of pass and fail

logic  -

1. if date_a < date_b, then consider date_a else date_b (the date which is considered  say imp_date), after that
2. if date_c - imp_date < 60 then pass else fail

and then in a bar chart , x axis contains bars - pass and fail, Y axis contains counts of pass and fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like all you'd need to do is use the following expression either as a calculated field in your data load or just directly in your bar chart:

`if( [date_c] - if( [date_a] < [date_b], [date_a], [date_b]) < 60 , 'Pass', 'Fail' )`

That would result in a bar chart that would look something like this:

[image: Qlik Sense bar chart with example results]